# Make react-select drop down display only with searchable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select and it working okay. However I would like to twitch it so than when I highlight it, it does not show the dropdown list until I enter something (searchable) then it shows the dropdown with matching options.

```
const options = [
 { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
 { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
 { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select 
   options={options} 
  />
)
```

Basically I want it to behave like an autocomplete. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the menu (dropdown) as controlled by using the prop called `menuIsOpen` and set it to `true` when you have text in the input. For tracking the text in the input you can use `onInputChange`.

Here is the code to make it controlled based on input value:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      onInputChange={(input) => {
        if (input) {
          setMenuIsOpen(true);
        } else {
          setMenuIsOpen(false);
        }
      }}
      menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
    />
  );
};
```